Getting error "Failed to fetch dynamically imported module" while running wdio run ./wdio.conf.js in React
I am getting error
Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:59543/node_modules/.vite/deps/@testing-library_react.js?v=b209e3fd: TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://localhost:59543/node_modules/.vite/deps/@testing-library_react.js?v=b209e3fd while running command npx wdio run ./wdio.conf.js
Webdriver config looks like this:
exports.config = {
    runner: ['browser', {
        preset: 'react',
        headless: false
    }],
    specs: [
        "./tests/**.jsx"
    ],
    exclude: [],
    maxInstances: 10,
    capabilities: [{
        browserName: 'chrome'
    }],
    logLevel: 'info',
    bail: 0,
    waitforTimeout: 10000,
    connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,
    connectionRetryCount: 3,
    framework: 'mocha',
    reporters: ['spec'],
    mochaOpts: {
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 60000
    },
    webpackConfig: {
        path: "./webpack.config.js",
    }
}

my test suite looks like this:
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'

describe('React Component Testing', () => {
  it('increments value on click', async () => {
    // The render method returns a collection of utilities to query your component.
    const { getByText } = render(<></>)

    
  })
})

I have also installed vite in package,json
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "publishConfig": {
    "registry": "
  },
  "scripts": {
    "wdio": "wdio run ./wdio.conf.js"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@dotlottie/react-player": "1.6.3",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.195",
    "@types/prop-types": "^15.7.8",
    "classnames": "2.5.1",
    "lit": "^2.5.0",
    "lit-html": "^2.8.0",
    "mobx": "^5.9.0",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react-window": "^1.8.10",
    "sass": "1.75.0",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods": "7.18.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "7.21.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-object-assign": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "7.10.4",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.10.13",
    "@types/jest": "29.5.1",
    "@types/lodash-es": "4.17.7",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.59.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.59.5",
    "add": "2.0.6",
    "babel-es6-polyfill": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-import-rename": "^1.0.1",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "core-js": "3.30.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "eslint": "^8.40.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^3.5.5",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.7.1",
    "eslint-plugin-lit": "1.8.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-wc": "1.5.0",
    "extract-loader": "5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.5.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.4.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^2.0.0",
    "jest-html-reporter": "^3.1.3",
    "jest-junit": "^6.3.0",
    "jest-svg-transformer": "1.0.0",
    "jest-transform-stub": "^2.0.0",
    "lit-scss-loader": "2.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "2.7.5",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react": "^16.8.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.2",
    "sass-loader": "13.2.2",
    "scss-loader": "0.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "ts-loader": "9.4.2",
    "typescript": "5.0.4",
    "url-loader": "4.1.1",
    "webpack": "5.79.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "5.0.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "4.13.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.61",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "@wdio/browser-runner": "^8.32.3",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.32.3",
    "@wdio/globals": "^8.32.3",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.32.3",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.32.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  }
}



